# SQL Server 2008 r2: How to check all views for runtime errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, runtime-error

I have a LOT of views in the database.
Each view ofc refers to one or more tables.
There was some work done with those tables (alter, delete columns) and now i need to check all views for any **runtime** errors.

I went straithforward: got list of all views, iterated over it and launch **SELECT TOP 0 * FROM view_name** dynamically so any errors should appear in the Messages pane.

This is my code

```
DECLARE @view_name_template varchar(max) = '%'
DECLARE @columnList varchar(75) = '*'
--------------------------
DECLARE @tmp_views AS TABLE (view_name varchar(max))
DECLARE @view_name varchar(max)
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @num int = 1
DECLARE @total_count int

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO @tmp_views 
SELECT name FROM sys.views
WHERE name LIKE @view_name_template

SELECT @total_count = COUNT(*) FROM sys.views WHERE name LIKE @view_name_template

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT view_name FROM @tmp_views ORDER BY LOWER(view_name)

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @view_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT TOP 0 ' + @columnList + ' FROM ' + @view_name
       PRINT CAST(@num as varchar(31)) + '/' + CAST(@total_count as varchar(31)) + ' ' + @sqlCommand

       EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @view_name         
       SET @num = @num + 1
END  

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

It works fine except it completely freezes on some views (select from those views in other window works extremely fast and fine). I think it is server a memory overflow issue or something similar.

Tell me please: what is the lightweighiest way to check view has errors or not? Maybe SQL Server has a special function or stored procedure?

Comment: On the tables you edited, right click the table names and click "View Dependencies" to see any related objects/views, that will make your task a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

The code is not "hanging".  It is waiting for the view to run, despite the `top 0`.

SQL Server offers several ways of testing queries.  In addition to the `top 0`, you also have:

- `set parseonly1
- `set noexec on`

And then the more recent `sp_describe_first_result_set`.

Each of these do different things.  `parseonly` checks for syntax errors but doesn't look at table layouts.  I believe `noexec` completely compiles the query, creating the execution plan.  `top 0` will compile the query and also run it.

In some cases, the optimizer may not recognize that a query that returns no rows might need to do no work.  For instance, there might be subqueries that are run despite the `top 0`, and this is causing the delay.

Two approaches.  The first is to use `noexec on` (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx)).  The second, if feasible, would be to create another database with the same structure and no data.  You can then test the queries on that database.

Comment: I'm curious: Is there any case where the optimizer cannot delete all operators below a top 0? Sounds like a simple optimization. For `WHERE 0=1` it reliably deletes everything.

Comment: @usr . . . I recall that a complicated subquery with an aggregation would cause this behavior.  That was on SQL Server 2008, and the optimizer may have improved since then.

Comment: Just syntax checking isnt match my case. I need exactly runtime check. 'set noexec on' doesnt work too, because it outputs nothing - nor select results not output in Result pane. There is no 'sp_describe_first_result_set' in my SQL Server 2008 r2.

Comment: @DoctorCoder . . . Then consider creating an empty test database and testing the queries there.  You can script out the database without data using SQL Server Management Studio.